# Retrieve updated rows in AFTER UPDATE trigger Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm writing a AFTER UPDATE trigger in postgresql.

Actualy I need to get at least one row after update in STATEMENT LEVEL trigger, but there is no OLD or NEW variable there.

In FOR EACH ROW trigger I didn't manage to find a sort of batch_last param.
But to do my procedure FOR EACH ROW is expensive.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide proper information: Your version of Postgres, at least  minimal table definition, trigger function and trigger you tried (even if it's not working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary table (so that it will visible only in the session). In the row level trigger you insert the rows into the temporary table, in the statement level trigger you select (and delete) from the temporary table.

Comment: Sounds nice, but it's a pity that psql doesn't have such native functionality.
And I should to give privileges for DDL statements to user.

Comment: You can `create table if not exists` in the triggers directly, so that the users don't need the DDL privileges.